How to configure programatically Logback in Groovy?
I have this Groovy Lockback configuration:
/*
 * Copyright (c) Deutsche Post DHL
 */

package de.deutschepost.adm.logging

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger
import ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
import ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout
import ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent
import ch.qos.logback.core.Appender
import ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants
import ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder
import ch.qos.logback.core.filter.Filter
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender
import ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.ContextAwareBase
import ch.qos.logback.core.spi.FilterReply
import de.deutschepost.adm.features.ManifestReader
import de.deutschepost.adm.monitoring.OperationalMonitor
import de.deutschepost.adm.utils.ConfUtil
import de.deutschepost.adm.utils.Environment
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

import static ch.qos.logback.classic.Level.*

/** logback custom Configurator provider using service-provider loading facility.
 * NOTE: this Configurator is registered as service provider
 * via the file ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.Configurator
 * located in /src/main/resources/META-INF/services
 */
@CompileStatic
class LogbackConfigurator extends ContextAwareBase implements Configurator {

    String shortVersion = ManifestReader.readManifestProductPackageVersion()

    // Developer friendly format:
    String fileFormat = "%d{'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS'} [%t] %-5p %c{0} - %optCode%m%n"
    String logDetailsFile = "ADM.CLIENT.${shortVersion}.log"

    // number of days to keep the logs
    static Integer maxLogFilesStorageDays = ConfUtil.getValue('maxLogFilesStorageDays',
            185) as Integer // 6 months

    static String logDirAdm = "C:\\LOG\\DHL\\ADM"
    static String logConsole = ConfUtil.getValue("log.console", true)

    @Override
    void configure(LoggerContext lc) {
        addInfo("Setting up default configuration.")

        Map<String, String> ruleRegistry = (Map) lc
                .getObject(CoreConstants.PATTERN_RULE_REGISTRY)
        if (ruleRegistry == null) {
            ruleRegistry = new HashMap<String, String>()
            lc.putObject(CoreConstants.PATTERN_RULE_REGISTRY, ruleRegistry)
        }
        ruleRegistry.put('monitorCode', MarkerNameConverter.class.name)
        ruleRegistry.put('optCode', OptMarkerNameConverter.class.name)

        Logger rootLogger = lc.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME)
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender = buildConsoleAppender(lc)
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> appAppender = buildAppAppender(lc)

        if (ConfUtil.getValue("log.verbose", Environment.DEV == Environment.current)) {
            /**
             * Local development configuration:
             */
            lc.getLogger('de.deutschepost.adm').setLevel(toLevel(
                    ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.de.deutschepost.adm',
                            'DEBUG')))
            rootLogger.setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.root', 'INFO')))
            if (logConsole) {
                rootLogger.addAppender(consoleAppender)
            }
            rootLogger.addAppender(appAppender)
        } else {
            /**
             *     Production configuration:
             */
            // Set general log level:
            lc.getLogger('de.deutschepost.adm')
                    .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.de.deutschepost.adm', 'INFO')))
            // log job execution as "DEBUG QuartzJobFactory - Producing instance of Job 'DEFAULT.$jobName', class=$jobClass"
            lc.getLogger('de.deutschepost.adm.scheduler.QuartzJobFactory')
                    .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.de.deutschepost.adm.scheduler.QuartzJobFactory',
                            'DEBUG')))

            // Attach all loggers:
            rootLogger.setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.root', 'INFO')))
            if (logConsole) {
                rootLogger.addAppender(consoleAppender)
            }
            rootLogger.addAppender(appAppender)
        }
        Logger touch = lc.getLogger('touch')
        touch.setLevel(INFO)
        touch.addAppender(appAppender)
        touch.addAppender(consoleAppender)
        touch.setAdditive(false)

        lc.getLogger('com.agimatec.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseImpl')
                .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.com.agimatec.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseImpl',
                        'WARN')))
        // prevent logging password

        lc.getLogger('com.agimatec.dbmigrate.util.ReconnectScriptVisitor')
                .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.
                        getValue('log.level.com.agimatec.dbmigrate.util.ReconnectScriptVisitor',
                                'WARN'))) // prevent logging password
        lc.getLogger('de.deutschepost.adm.config')
                .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.de.deutschepost.adm.config', 'INFO')))
        // prevent logging password

        // for dbmigrate
        lc.getLogger('com.agimatec').setLevel(INFO)
        lc.getLogger('commons.sql').setLevel(INFO)
        lc.getLogger('org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer').setLevel(DEBUG)

        // verbose logging for hibernate/ehcache 2nd level caching
        //logger('org.hibernate.cache', DEBUG)
        lc.getLogger('org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory')
                .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.
                        getValue('log.level.org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.AbstractEhcacheRegionFactory',
                                'ERROR'))) // do not log WARN when using a default cache


        // camel tracer
        lc.getLogger('org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor')
                .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.getValue('log.level.org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor',
                        'INFO')))
        lc.getLogger('org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl')
                .setLevel(toLevel(ConfUtil.
                        getValue('log.level.org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl',
                                'DEBUG'))) // to see when Hibernate SessionFactory is closed on shutdown

        if (ConfUtil.getValue('jdbc.logsql', false)) {
            lc.getLogger('org.hibernate.SQL').setLevel(DEBUG)
        }
        if (ConfUtil.getValue('jdbc.logtype', false)) {
            lc.getLogger('org.hibernate.type').setLevel(TRACE)
        }
        if (ConfUtil.getValue('jdbc.logta', false)) {
            lc.getLogger('org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager').setLevel(DEBUG)
        }

        // spring transaction
        Logger spring = lc.getLogger('org.springframework.transaction.interceptor')
        spring.setLevel(TRACE)
        spring.setAdditive(false)

        if (logConsole) {
            addInfo('** Logging configured')
        } else {
            String logfile = new File(logDirAdm, logDetailsFile).path
            addInfo("** Logging configured >> $logfile")
        }

    }

    private static RollingFileAppender buildRollingFileAppender(LoggerContext lc, String name,
                                                                String format, String file, String fileNamePattern) {
        LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = buildPatternLayoutEncoder(format, lc)

        RollingFileAppender logFileAppender = new RollingFileAppender()
        logFileAppender.setContext(lc)
        logFileAppender.setName("logFile")
        logFileAppender.setEncoder(encoder)
        logFileAppender.setAppend(true)
        logFileAppender.setFile("C:\\LOG\\DHL\\ADM\\ADM.CLIENT.dev.log")

        TimeBasedRollingPolicy logFilePolicy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy()
        logFilePolicy.setContext(lc)
        logFilePolicy.setParent(logFileAppender)
        logFilePolicy.setFileNamePattern("C:\\LOG\\DHL\\ADM\\ADM.CLIENT.dev-%d{yyyy-MM-dd_HH}.log")
        logFilePolicy.setMaxHistory(365)
        logFilePolicy.start()

        logFileAppender.setRollingPolicy(logFilePolicy)
        logFileAppender.start()




        return logFileAppender
    }

    private static RollingFileAppender prepareRollingFileAppender(LoggerContext lc, String name, String format,
                                                                  String file, String fileNamePattern) {
        RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> rfa = new RollingFileAppender()
        rfa.setContext(lc)
        rfa.setName(name)
        LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = buildPatternLayoutEncoder(format, lc)
        rfa.setFile(new File(logDirAdm, file).path)
        TimeBasedRollingPolicy policy = new TimeBasedRollingPolicy()
        policy.setContext(lc)
        policy.setFileNamePattern(new File(logDirAdm, fileNamePattern).path)
        policy.setMaxHistory(maxLogFilesStorageDays)
        policy.setParent(rfa)
        policy.start()
        rfa.setRollingPolicy(policy)
        rfa.setEncoder(encoder)

        rfa.setAppend(true)

        // This filter is needed to track the adm error messages for statistics
        rfa.addFilter(new Filter<ILoggingEvent>() {
            @Override
            FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent event) {
                if (event.getLevel() == ERROR) {
                    OperationalMonitor.instance.setMetric(OperationalMonitor.Metric.AdmErrorCount)
                }
                return FilterReply.NEUTRAL
            }
        })

        return rfa
    }

    private static Appender<ILoggingEvent> buildConsoleAppender(LoggerContext lc) {
        //Developer friendly format with ANSI color sequences:
        def consoleFormat = "%d{'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS'} [%t] %highlight(%-5p) %c{0} - %optCode%m%n"
        ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> ca = new ConsoleAppender<>()
        ca.setContext(lc)
        ca.setName("CONSOLE")
        LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = buildPatternLayoutEncoder(consoleFormat, lc)

        ca.setEncoder(encoder)
        ca.start()
        return ca
    }

    private Appender<ILoggingEvent> buildAppAppender(LoggerContext lc) {
        // Same as console, but written to file for book-keeping:
        String name = "APP"
        String format = fileFormat
        String file = logDetailsFile
        String fileNamePattern = "ADM.CLIENT.${shortVersion}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz"

        return buildRollingFileAppender(lc, name, format, file, fileNamePattern)
    }

    private static LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> buildPatternLayoutEncoder(String format, LoggerContext lc) {
        PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout()

        layout.setPattern(format)

        LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent> encoder = new LayoutWrappingEncoder<ILoggingEvent>()
        encoder.setContext(lc)

        layout.setContext(lc)
        layout.start()
        encoder.setLayout(layout)
        encoder.start()
        encoder
    }
}

I need log logger messages into C:\LOG\DHL\ADM\ADM.CLIENT.dev.log, but when I run application, It doesnt log into this file. In debug it seems that this code on application startup runs. Also   addInfo("Setting up default configuration.") doesnt work.
I see this question : TimeBasedRollingPolicy logback programmatically, but resolution of this question in my case doesnt work. Thanks for help

why do you need it from code? are you able to use groovy config file? https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html
